# How to make this inference: Degree of a node in a graph is significantly diffenrent from poisson distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, graph-theory, probability-distributions, bayesian

I am working on Gene-Gene interaction graphs. I build a graph by adding edges between genes (nodes) which show statistical interaction in predicting a quantitative parameter value (say, brain volume) in a multiple regression model.

For creating a well-connected graph, I have lowered the p-value threshold in order to include as many edges as possible, so it is likely that a proportion of these links are false-positives.

My question is that, if some nodes show a very high degree centrality‎ which is very unlikely to happen in a random Erdős–Rényi model (Poisson distribution), can I make a statistical inference that this node is biologically relevant to the brain size parameter, even if the graph does not show a Erdős–Rényi degree distribution pattern?
What is the best statistical test for this, and if there exists one, is it also important to consider multiple-comparisons in this test?

Thanks,

Sourena Soheili-Nezhad, M.D.

Comment: You might have more luck with this question on http://stats.stackexchange.com.